# SQL relations between Product, Store, and Price

Tags: sql, relational-database

I got Computer-Table, Store-Table, and Price-Table,

What would be the best way to establish relationships among these three, so if I pull out a Computer-Record I would see all Prices at different Stores.

Computer to Price is Many-To-Many? What about Computer - Store ?

The whole concept is that the same Computer priced differently at different stores.

Please advise what would be the best way to set the relations.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. What is your textbook? How have you followed it? Propose a design. You are approaching this wrong. First identify what business/application relation(ship)s/associations (represented by tables) you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

i think you would have a computer table (products), store table (stores) and "computer store" table that lists the computer id, store id and the price.

You should not have the same computer at the same store for multiple prices.

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, you can hold many to many relationship on `Computer-Store` in the `Price` table.

```
Computer
- Id

Price
- Id
- ComputerId
- StoreId
- Price

Store
- Id
```

In this way, you can get ability to keep computer price for per store.

Comment: Ok, so I shop by the Computer ID I could see all available offers at different stores?

Comment: By providing a simple join, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Computer and Store table can have Unique Product_ID and Store Id respectively.
Price table can have Price details for combination of Product_Id and Store_Id.